# alphabetic keyboard macro "counter"?

Tags: keyboard-macros, counter

I very much {like, use} the `kmacro-*-counter` family of commands. However I sometimes find myself needing to generate alphabetic sequences (e.g., A, B, C, ...) instead of integer sequences (e.g., 1, 2, 3 ...). I can sorta see how to do this in 2 passes using `query-replace-regexp` and something like `make-string`, but that means 1st generating the integer sequence and then replacing it.

Is there an easier way? Particularly, is there some {command, function, package} that will support a usecase like

1. `M-x foo-set-alpha-counter A`
2. *(loop)* `M-x foo-insert-counter`

?

Comment: I don't use macros, but you may find it helpful to know that Emacs uses numbers for letters such as `(char-to-string 65)` is the capital letter "A".  And, this increments sequentially, e.g., `(char-to-string 66)` is the capital letter "B".  Lowercase letters begin at 97; e.g., `(char-to-string 97)` is the lowercase letter "a"; and, it continues sequentially; e.g., `(char-to-string 98)` is the lowercase letter "b".  To check the number, you can do the reverse -- `(string-to-char "A")` returns the number 65.

Comment: Coding is according to the ASCII standard. See 'man ascii'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the function `kmacro-set-format`, normally bound to `C-x C-k C-f`, to change the (printf-style) format used to insert the macro counter. You can set it to `%c` to treat the value of the macro counter as an ASCII code.

For example to produce a letter sequence like `ABCDEF`: set the format to `%c`, start the macro counter at 65 which is the ASCII code for `A`, then record a macro that inserts the counter and run it 6 times, say:

```
C-x C-k C-f %c RET C-u 65 <f3> <f3> C-6 <f4>
```

As a neat extra touch, if you change the format inside the keyboard macro, the change only affects that particular macro. So, after running the above, the format will still be `%c` for the next keyboard macro, but if instead you do:

```
C-u 65 <f3> C-x C-k C-f %c RET <f3> C-6 <f4>
```

then the `%c` is local to that macro.

`%d` to go back to numbers.

Comment: Thanks! Works great, plus this validates my otherwise-bizarre notion that my laminated ASCII-code card from 1982 would eventually prove handy `:-)`

Comment: @TomRoche :) If you ever loose that laminated card and you use GNU/Linux, you can run `man ascii` to see a nice chart (`M-x man` or `M-x woman` from within Emacs).

Comment: @Omar Awesome tip. Is there any way to be able to just insert the char and have emacs convert it?

Comment: Not as part of that key sequence; but you can certainly ask Emacs what the number is beforehand, by evaluating the read syntax for a character.  E.g. `M-: ?A` tells you `65` (or vice versa, evaluating `65` tells you `?A`).

Comment: If it helps, in elisp code you would use the `read-char` function to ask the user to type a character, and obtain that value.